# How to access value of page controls to the run time added user control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that is being integrated to the page on run time, now here on the page i have a few HTML control whose values need to save too, as i have written the save method logic to the user control because it has many content their to save in DB, but what i am missing is how to save the page content to the DB using the same Save Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you just need to pass the values to the UC, just declare public properties in your UC and assign the values at runtime:

Check the following example:

### Public properties approach

**In the UC code behind**

```
public string Street
{
    get
    {
        return this.ViewState["c"] as string;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["c"] = value;
    }
}

public void Save()
{
    ...
    // your logic to save the UC data
    // save the custom properties too, this.Street
{
```

**In the ASPX code behind**

```
this.myAddressTemplateControl.Street = myOtherControl.Text;
```

### Accessing directly the page object

**In the UC code behind**

```
 this.Page.FindControl("myPageControlID");
```

Comment: i have created the property in the user control but ualble to set it in the page, doing it in the following way...    uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/DocumentSpreadSheet.ascx");
                pnlDetails.Controls.Add(uc);
                //this.Page.FindControl("");
                break;
            but no success, culd you tell me what acualy i need to inset in findcontrol method

Comment: How and where are you creating your user control? In which page event? Can you share some code? I am thinking the problem is the creation of the dynamic UC